# objdump of a .so file? need help to understand the messages

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk

I am developing a native application related to streaming, i am facing some problems in my c module... and what i have is some message from Logcat

---

Here is the Logcat message

```
INFO/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
11-17 12:40:07.550: INFO/DEBUG(28): pid: 5957, tid: 5957  >>> com.mmstwo <<<
11-17 12:40:07.561: INFO/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
11-17 12:40:07.561: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r0 00000354  r1 00129100  r2 0000000c  r3 deadd00d
11-17 12:40:07.561: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r4 00000026  r5 ad07ff50  r6 00000000  r7 fffe72f8
11-17 12:40:07.579: INFO/DEBUG(28):  r8 afe3bdfc  r9 4509f020  10 00000000  fp 00135a40
11-17 12:40:07.590: INFO/DEBUG(28):  ip ad080160  sp bef28f90  lr afe14cf7  pc ad035452  cpsr 20000030
11-17 12:40:07.840: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc 00035452  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-17 12:40:07.850: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00027a98  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-17 12:40:07.869: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 00027bba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-17 12:40:07.879: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc 0002d98e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

---

```
11-17 12:40:07.901: INFO/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc 0000142e  /data/data/com.mmstwo/lib/libnstreamer.so
```

this is the line that represents the c class which i use.

---

as per comments on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171259/problem-in-my-appliction-cant-understand-what-does-the-error-message-says) i followed url given by rahul and dumped my .so file to a text file.

here is that text file

```
 141e:  4a2d        ldr r2, [pc, #180]  (14d4 <Java_com_mmstwo_NativeParser_stringFromJNI+0x408>)
    1420:   4b2d        ldr r3, [pc, #180]  (14d8 <Java_com_mmstwo_NativeParser_stringFromJNI+0x40c>)
    1422:   2184        movs    r1, #132
    1424:   5846        ldr r6, [r0, r1]
    1426:   18aa        adds    r2, r5, r2
    1428:   18eb        adds    r3, r5, r3
    142a:   4651        mov r1, sl
    142c:   1c38        adds    r0, r7, #0
    142e:   47b0        blx r6
    1430:   4b2a        ldr r3, [pc, #168]  (14dc <Java_com_mmstwo_NativeParser_stringFromJNI+0x410>)
    1432:   4669        mov r1, sp
```

so as per the [post in google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/cce1848b309ed56c/5679f82418283f26?pli=1) and specially suggested by Nicklas Ansman i had shown the snippet which is around my desired line `142e`.

Now can anyone here who can tell what does `47b0        blx r6` means?

What i knew is it is something written in assembly language that i don't know. So I need your help in understanding that line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, fault address "deadd00d" indicates a deliberate VM abort.  Before aborting the VM writes an explanation to the log file; you should see it up above what you pasted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`blx` jumps to the address given by the argument; here, to the address which is currently loaded in register r6. Also, the return address (namely the address of the `ldr` opcode which is located immediately after the `blx`) is written in the special-purpose register lr (as "link register").

This corresponds to an indirect call. In C it would look like a call through a function pointer. on some platforms with dynamic linking, a simple function call to a function can also become something like what you see here.

Anyway, the register dump shows r6 to be 0 at that point, hence the segfault. r6 was loaded from the `ldr` opcode on address 1424. This loads r6 from what was at address r0+r1, r1 being set to 132 just above. r0 is the conventional register for the first argument to a C function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, it's more than i have expected.

Comment: And one more thing... Is there any guide available that have detailed list of all assembly commands with proper explaination?

Comment: You can get the ARM Architecture Reference Manual from http://infocenter.arm.com/ (you have to register but it is free). You will also need the procedure call standard (ATPCS or AAPCS, depending on the generation -- the ARM world is a big mess): the procedure call standard defines in what registers are the arguments, how the stack is maintained and aligned, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok find it out with some freak digging on google.'

`blx` mean `Branch and link with exchange (BLX)` and if i'm not wrong it's similar to `return withValue` type of java statement.

it helped me to start debugging in native code also......